# How to prevent css transform animation from jumping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to create a slider using CSS transforms combined with `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`. So far it works fine, except for one thing:

While I remove `.behind` and add `.behinder` (which is a stupid name for a class), the images on the right side jump instantly to the left side and than transition themselves to the right again.

This causes some kind of "flickering", as you can see in this snippet:

```js
var slider = $('#slider');

// to the right
var slideRight = function() {
  
  // switch state
  var dumb = slider.find('.behinder.left');
  slider.find('.behinder.right').removeClass('right').addClass('left');
  slider.find('.behind.right').removeClass('behind').addClass('behinder');
  slider.find('.center').removeClass('center').addClass('behind right');
  slider.find('.behind.left').removeClass('behind left').addClass('center');
  dumb.removeClass('behinder').addClass('behind');
}

$('#right').on('click', function(){
  slideRight();
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0% 5%;
}

#card-slider-fullwidth {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
}
#slider img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#slider img.center {
  z-index: 50;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#slider img.behind {
  z-index: 30;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.9);
          transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.9);
}
#slider img.behind.left {
  margin-left: calc( (100% - 200px) / 3 * -1);
}
#slider img.behind.right {
  margin-left: calc( (100% - 200px) / 3);
}
#slider img.behinder {
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) scale(0.8);
          transform: translateX(0) scale(0.8);
}
#slider img.behinder.left {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  margin-left: calc( (100% - 200px) / 8 * -1);
}
#slider img.behinder.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: calc( (100% - 200px) / 8 * -1);
}

#right {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="right">Switch, baby.</div>

<div id="card-slider-fullwidth">
  <div id="slider">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?image=100" alt="100" class="behinder left">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?image=200" alt="200" class="behind left">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?image=320" alt="300" class="center">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?image=400" alt="400" class="behind right">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?image=500" alt="500" class="behinder right">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

There is a **[CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/marianrick/pen/mMzRgj)** as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok actually the solution was quite simple. I have used two properties, to position the elements:

- `margin-left: x;`
- `transform: translateX();`

As at one point I have removed `translateX();` completely, the images have been jumping. So to solve this problem, I rearranged the layout using only `margin-left` to offset the images.

You can check the working solution with an update of the scss:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;

    &.center {
      z-index: 50;
      margin-left: 0;
    }

    &.behind {
      z-index: 30;
      margin-left: -20px;
      transform: translateX(-50%) scale(.9);

      &.right {
        margin-left: 20px;
      }
    }

    &.behinder {
      z-index: 10;
      margin-left: -40px;
      transform: translateX(-50%) scale(.8);

      &.right {
        margin-left: 40px;
      }
    }
  }
```